# Excel: TEXTJOIN with XLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

I need to look up values and separate the multiple matches with `TEXTJOIN`.

Here is the input data on **Sheet1**:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 4003 | Bob3 |
| 4003 | Tom3 |
| 4003 | Jim3 |
| 4004 | Bob4 |
| 4004 | Tom4 |
| 4004 | Jim4 |
| 4005 | Bob5 |
| 4005 | Tom5 |
| 4005 | Jim5 |

**Sheet2**: with the lookup values:

| Lookup |
| --- |
| 4003 |
| 4004 |
| 4005 |

Here is the expected output in **Sheet2**:

| Lookup | Expected Result |
| --- | --- |
| 4003 | Bob3 | Tom3 | Jim3 |
| 4004 | Bob4 | Tom4 | Jim4 |
| 4005 | Bob5 | Tom5 | Jim5 |

Here the formula I am trying to use so far:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" | ",TRUE,XLOOKUP([@[ID]],Sheet1[ID],Sheet1[Name]),
 XLOOKUP([@[ID]],Sheet1[ID],Sheet1[Name]))
```

This returns the same item concatenated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `XLOOKUP()` will return only first occurrence of lookup value. Use `FILTER()` instead. Post few sample data as well as show your desired output.

Comment: @Harun24hr Please see my updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following Excel Table (`TB_IdName`) in range `A1-B10`:

You can try this on cell `E2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" | ",,FILTER(TB_IdName[Name], TB_IdName[ID]=D2))
```

and expand down the above formula.

Here are the lookup values and the corresponding output:

[image: sample excel file]